# how to fix scale 1:4000 to export map in PDF ol3

Tags: openlayers

This is my code to export map in pdf but i want to fix this map in 1:4000 scale the n export or print it to pdf.

```
var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]
  };

  var exportElement =  document.getElementById("export-pdf");
  exportElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log("hi");
  if (exportElement.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1) {
    return;
  }
  exportElement.className += ' disabled';

  var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
  var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
  var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById('button-label');
  var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
  var dim = dims[format];
  var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
  var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
  var size = /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize());
  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

  map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
    //var tileQueue = map.getTileQueue();

    // To prevent potential unexpected division-by-zero
    // behaviour, tileTotalCount must be larger than 0.

    //var tileTotalCount = tileQueue.getCount() || 1;
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      //var tileCount = tileQueue.getCount();
      //var ratio = 1 - tileCount / tileTotalCount;
      //buttonLabelElement.innerText = ' ' + (100 * ratio).toFixed(1) + '%';
      //if (ratio == 1 && !tileQueue.getTilesLoading()) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        buttonLabelElement.innerText = label;
        var canvas = event.context.canvas;
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
        pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
        pdf.save('map.pdf');
        map.setSize(size);
        map.getView().fit(extent, size);
        map.renderSync();
        exportElement.className =
            exportElement.className.replace(' disabled', '');
     // }
    }, 100);
  });

  map.setSize([width, height]);
  map.getView().fit(extent, /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize()));
  map.renderSync();

}, false);
```

any help would be highly appriciated.

I updated the code us per your suggestion still map is not exported to pdf.

```
//print map 
    var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]
  };

  var exportElement =  document.getElementById("export-pdf");
  exportElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log("hi");
  if (exportElement.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1) {
    return;
  }
  exportElement.className += ' disabled';

  var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
  var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
  var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById('button-label');
  var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
 var scale = 4000;

var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);

var dim = dims[format];
var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
var size = map.getSize();
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;

map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
    console.log('hiiii');
     buttonLabelElement.innerText = label;
  var canvas = event.context.canvas;
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
  pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
  pdf.save('map.pdf');
  map.setSize(size);
  map.getView().fit(extent, size);
   exportElement.className =
            exportElement.className.replace(' disabled', '');
}); 


var printPointResolution = (scale * dim[0]) / (width * 1000);
var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution
var printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);        

map.setSize([width, height]);
mapView.fit(extent, (map.getSize()));
mapView.setZoom(printZoom);

}, false);
```

Comment: no one to help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not familiar with ol3, this will be for ol5.

To print in desired scale we neeed to calculate the zoom at which printed map will have that scale. First we need formula to calculate scale of printed map:

```
var scale =  (width * mapPointResolution * 1000) / dim[0];
```

where `mapPointResolution` is map resolution at the center of displayed map:

```
var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
```

We will also need `mapResolutionFactor`:

```
var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;
```

**EDIT1:** Original calculation of `printPointResolution` was wrong because it didn't take into account print DPI resolution. To get the correct value two different formulas for print width in pixels have to be combined:

```
width = (scale * printDim[0]) / (mapPointResolution * 1000);
width = printDim[0] * resolution / 25.4;
```

From this we get map point resolution for print at desired scale:

```
mapPointResolution = (scale * 25.4) / (resolution * 1000);
```

And finally from this we can get required zoom for print:

```
printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);
```

To put all this togeter (just the print part):

```
var scale = 4000;

var mapView = map.getView();
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);

var dim = dims[format];
var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
var size = map.getSize();
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

var mapView = map.getView();
var currZoom = mapView.getZoom();  //edit2
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;

map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
  var canvas = event.context.canvas;
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
  pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
  pdf.save('map.pdf');
  map.setSize(size);
  // map.getView().fit(extent, size);  //edit2: not needed
  mapView.setZoom(currZoom);  // edit2: set original zoom
});

var printPointResolution = (scale * 25.4) /(resolution * 1000);  // edit1: corrected
var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
var printZoom = mapView.getZoomForResolution(printResolutionAtEquator);        

map.setSize([width, height]);
// mapView.fit(extent, (map.getSize())); - edit1: removed, not neccessary
mapView.setZoom(printZoom);
```

**EDIT2:** Corrected code to return to original zoom after print.

Comment: Thanks TomazicM for helping me but pdf is not being downloaded. Only Mapview is changed.

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: yes TomazicM, it is showing in console  "Active resource loading counts reached a per-frame limit while the tab was in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is brought to the foreground."

Comment: i think it never come within this function map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) { });  that's why map is not exported to pdf.

Comment: I also edited my post with new code as per your suggestion. Please go through it.

Comment: It looks like you have problems with resources. What print resolution are you using? Try with something low, for example 72. Since it looks like you are using Chrome, this answer might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456544/form-submission-is-blocked-while-submitting-the-form-in-hubspot

Comment: Thanks TomazicM your code works like a charm in case of  ol5 so that i changed my code from ol3 to ol5 but still i am trying to find solution for the same in ol3. I am sure in ol3  problem is with rendercomplete event because it never goes within rendercomplete when i tried to console somthing within rendercomplete 
 function.

Comment: ol3 does not have `rendercomplete` map event. It has similar `postrender` event. Documentation says it's experimental (https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.Map.html), but you can try it.

Comment: I tried postrender but it does not work.

Comment: I tried it myself with ol3 and then checked ol3 docs. ol3 does not support `getZoomForResolution` view method and does not use canvas, so `var canvas = event.context.canvas` fails.

Comment: TomazicM sir..is your code applicable for all desired scale whether it is 1:4000 or 1:8000??

Comment: Yes, just change value od `scale` variable.

Comment: heloo TomazicM .one query i have i e when map is exported to pdf label is showing blur in pdf. here label is important because label is as parcel no.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for ol3. Base code is taken from ol3 export to PDF example https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/export-pdf.html.

ol3 does not have `getZoomForResolution` view method, so I took simplifed formula just for this example from `getZoom` method:

```
desiredZoom = Math.log(mapView.getMaxResolution() / reqiredResolution) / Math.log(2);
```

The code for export to PDF at desired scale then looks like this:

```
var printScale = 4000;

var dim = dims[format];
var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
var size = map.getSize();
var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

var mapView = map.getView();
var currZoom = mapView.getZoom();  // edit1
var mapProjection = mapView.getProjection();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var viewCenter = mapView.getCenter();
var mapResolutionAtEquator = mapView.getResolution();
var mapPointResolution = ol.proj.getPointResolution(mapProjection, mapResolutionAtEquator, viewCenter);
var mapResolutionFactor = mapResolutionAtEquator / mapPointResolution;

var source = raster.getSource();

var tileLoadStart = function() {
  ++loading;
};

var tileLoadEnd = function() {
  ++loaded;
  if (loading === loaded) {
    var canvas = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      loading = 0;
      loaded = 0;
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
      pdf.save('map.pdf');
      source.un('tileloadstart', tileLoadStart);
      source.un('tileloadend', tileLoadEnd, canvas);
      source.un('tileloaderror', tileLoadEnd, canvas);
      map.setSize(size);
      // map.getView().fit(extent, size);  edit1: not needed
      mapView.setZoom(currZoom);  // edit1: return to original zoom
      map.renderSync();
      exportButton.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }, 100);
  }
};

map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
  source.on('tileloadstart', tileLoadStart);
  source.on('tileloadend', tileLoadEnd, event.context.canvas);
  source.on('tileloaderror', tileLoadEnd, event.context.canvas);
});

var mapView = map.getView();
var printPointResolution = (printScale * 25.4) / (resolution * 1000)
var printResolutionAtEquator = mapResolutionFactor * printPointResolution;
var printZoom = Math.log(mapView.getMaxResolution() / printResolutionAtEquator) / Math.log(2);

map.setSize([width, height]);
mapView.setZoom(printZoom);

map.renderSync();
```

**EDIT1:** Corrected code to return to original zoom after print.

Comment: Thanks a lot  TomazicM. If i want to print district name in map canvas then what i have to do?

Comment: Describe your wish in more detail an put it as a new question. And mark answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: In this line showing error raster is not defined "var source = raster.getSource();"

Comment: what is raster layer here because i already set a wms layer as baselayer which is required.

Comment: Look at the complete code of example where I took my code from: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/export-pdf.html.

Comment: TomazicM sir..is your code applicable for all desired scale whether it is 1:4000 or 1:8000??

Comment: Yes, just change value of `printScale` variable.

Comment: Could you help me in this please ? gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336741/export-openlayers-map-to-pdf-with-fixed-scale-and-different-pdf-formats